# How do you change layouts in nuxt3 inside a setup?

Tags: nuxt3

I need to have a custom layout or remove default layout for my signIn page. Based on [Nuxt3 docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/define-page-meta) you can set layout with `definePageMeta({layout: "custom"})` or remove `definePageMeta({layout: false})` however when I set it to false or "custom" I get a TypeError.

[image]

The definePageMeta does change the layout. However, there are instances where when you first load the signIn page it doesn't show anything and shows the TypeError above. Any advice on how to solve this issue is greatly appreciated!

Btw, I just recently started using nuxt3, never had this issue in nuxt2.

```
// sign in page
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLayout name="custom">
      <v-row>Sign In Page</v-row>
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: 'custom',
})
</script>


// layout custom.vue
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid>
        <slot />
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To create layout in nuxt 3 you must add `slot`.

```
// custom layout
<template>
  <div class="custom-layout">
     <slot/>
  </div>
</template>
```

and then in your page component add `layout: 'custom'` in `definePageMeta` in setup script.

```
<template>
// YOUR PAGE
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
definePageMeta({
  layout: "custom",
});
</script>
```

if you need `app.vue` you must add `NuxtLayout` to it

```
// app.vue
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

Comment: i do have the slot. So not sure why i'm encountering this problem.

Comment: did you remove `NuxtLayout` tag and check it works or not?

Comment: or did you remove app.vue?

Comment: Hello, yes I removed the app.vue since i have multiple pages.